# Replacing Negatives in an Array, Python

Tags: python, arrays

How do I write a function that replaces all negative numbers in an array with a 0. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
def negativesToZero(A):
    for x in A:
        if x < 0:
            A.append(0)
    else:
        pass
    print A 
A = ([[1,-2],\
      [-2,1]])
negativesToZero(A)
```

Comment: Grab a pencil and paper and go through this code by hand. You'll find that it does some strange things that you didn't want.

Comment: This works for 2 dimensional int lists such as A: [list(map(lambda x: x if x >= 0 else -x,a)) for a in A]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `A` is a list of lists:

```
>>> A = [[1, -2], [-2, 1]]

>>> for lst in A:
...     for i, val in enumerate(lst):
...         lst[i] = max(val, 0)

>>> print A
[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

Alternatively using list comprehensions:

```
>>> A = [[max(val, 0) for val in lst] for lst in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array operation, you should create a proper array to start with.

```
A=array([[1,-2],[-2,1]])
```

Array comprehensions like yours can be one-lined using boolean operations on indices:

```
A[A<0]=0
```

Of course you can frame it as a function:

```
def positive_attitude(x):
    x[x<0]=0
    return x
print positive_attitude(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through each sublist in the `list`. For each sublist, create a new one that turns any negative items into `0`. The tidiest way is with a comprehension:

```
A = [[1,-2], [-2,1]]
A = [[item if item >= 0 else 0 for item in l] for l in A]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive implementation that will work with *any* type of list, with *any* type of input in it:

```
def convertToZero(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if type(arr[i]) == int and arr[i] < 0:
            arr[i] = 0
        elif type(arr[i]) == list:
            convertToZero(arr[i])
    return arr

result = convertToZero( [[1,-2], ['hello',[-2,1]], [-1,'world']] )
print result
# [[1, 0], ['hello', [0, 1]], [0, 'world']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and easy to understand answer along the lines of what you were trying to do in the beginning:

```
def negativesToZero(A):
    index  = 0 #Track your index

    for x in A:
        if isinstance(x, list): #Calling the program recursively on nested lists
            A[index] = negativesToZero(x)

        elif x < 0:
            A[index] = 0 #Makes negatives 0

        else:
            pass #Ignores zeros and positives

        index += 1 #Move on to next index
    print A
    return A
```

If you don't want the unwanted inner print statements you can add an input variable (I will call it 'recur') to the function that makes only the non recursive call print:

```
def negativesToZero(A, recur = False):
  index  = 0

  for x in A:
    if isinstance(x, list):
      A[index] = negativesToZero(x, True)

    elif x < 0:
      A[index] = 0

    else:
      pass

    index += 1
  if recur == False: print A
  return A
```

**Result:**

```
A = ([[1,-2],\
     [-2,1],\
     [-5, -6], [4,7]])

negativesToZero(A)

>>>> [[1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [4, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

listOnums = np.random.normal(size = 300)
listOnums = listOnums.reshape(3,10,10)


def negToZero(arrayOnums):
    '''
    Takes an array of numbers, replaces values less than 0 with 0
    and retuns an array of numbers.
    '''
    dims = arrayOnums.shape
    flatNums = arrayOnums.flatten()

    for num,x in enumerate(flatNums):

        if x >= 0: pass
        else:
            flatNums[num] = 0

        arrayOnums = flatNums.reshape(dims)

    return arrayOnums

negToZero(listOnums)
```

Comment: Hope this is clearer if I spell it out but for loop can absolutely be replaced with list comprehension.